# parsing json inside an asyntask in android

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I fetch information from a json source from web inside an android service, inside a timer loop. some times, about 5% of times i get this error:

```
03-20 09:27:06.901: E/AndroidRuntime(401): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 09:27:06.901: E/AndroidRuntime(401): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 09:27:06.901: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:112)
03-20 09:27:06.901: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:90)
03-20 09:27:06.901: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
03-20 09:27:06.901: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
03-20 09:27:06.901: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at Dic.proj.pkg.notifService.parse_if_update(notifService.java:182)
03-20 09:27:06.901: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at Dic.proj.pkg.notifService$1$1$1.onPostExecute(notifService.java:151)
03-20 09:27:06.901: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at Dic.proj.pkg.notifService$1$1$1.onPostExecute(notifService.java:1)
03-20 09:27:06.901: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
03-20 09:27:06.901: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
03-20 09:27:06.901: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
03-20 09:27:06.901: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 09:27:06.901: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-20 09:27:06.901: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-20 09:27:06.901: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 09:27:06.901: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-20 09:27:06.901: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-20 09:27:06.901: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-20 09:27:06.901: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i user RestClient libraryfot parsing json. and this is my parse_if_update Asyntask:

```
public static String parse_if_update(String jsonResponse) {
    String update = "";
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
        update = json.getString("update");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return update;
}
```

whats wrong with this?  i think it related to my asyntask because my asyntask runs several times sometimes...

Comment: What's the code on this line: `notifService.java:182` ?

Answer (score 1):

The `NullPointerException` is thrown by the `JSONTokener`, which makes me think that your `jsonResponse` object is `null`. Add a check for this and you should be fine:

```
if (jsonResponse != null) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
    update = json.getString("update");
}

else
    update = "response was null!";
```

Comment: provide the whole notifService.java file and the new exception with the line number and I'll take a look. You can use http://paste.ubuntu.com